# invalid argument при попытке выполнить http запрос. Golang

Tags: linux, golang

Есть такой скрипт. Он мне нужен для нагрузочного тестирования:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "sync"
    "time"

    "github.com/BurntSushi/toml"
)

type Config struct {
    Urls              []string `toml:"urls"`
    Token             string   `toml:"token"`
    ActiveConnections int      `toml:"activeConnections"`
}

func makeRequest(url string, token string) {
    client := &http.Client{}
    for {
        req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }

        req.Header.Set("Authorization", fmt.Sprintf("Bearer %s", token))

        t0 := time.Now()
        resp, err := client.Do(req)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        } else {
            t1 := time.Now()
            fmt.Printf("Url: %s. Time: %v. %s\n", url, t1.Sub(t0), resp.Status)
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    http.DefaultClient.Timeout = time.Second * 10
    config := Config{}
    _, err := toml.DecodeFile("./config.toml", &config)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)
    for i := 0; i < config.ActiveConnections; i++ {
        for _, url := range config.Urls {
            go makeRequest(url, config.Token)
        }
    }
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Всё что он делает это спамит http запросами на указанные url. Сначала всё работает окей, но через некоторое время в консоли появляется такая ошибка:

```
Get <my_url>: dial tcp: lookup <my_domain>: invalid argument
```

`<my_url>` и `<my_domain>` я написал вместо реальных значений. Эта ошибка возвращается при `client.Do(req)`. Я не понимаю почему так происходит и что я должен сделать чтобы оно перестало так делать. Я пробовал на `1.15` и `1.16` версии, а также на разных url, проблема воспроизводится везде. Правда иногда раньше, иногда позже. Ubuntu 20.04

**Update:** Забыл сказать, что эта ошибка сыплется на все запросы после её появления. А если скрипт остановить и сразу же запустить то снова всё ок на какое-то время

Comment: Похоже, что Вы делаете слишком много одновременных запросов. попробуйте с помощью ulimit -n 10000 поднять себе кол-во доступных дескрипторов и запустить ещё раз.

Comment: все верно.  также посмотрите на программу wrk. `wrk -d 10s http://localhost:8080/api`, если вам просто надо быстро нагрузить, либо на loadrunner, если хотите подойти к задаче серьезнее

Comment: ну или выкинуть все эти поделки и использовать классику - ab

Comment: @KoVadim мне нужно было быстро накидать скрипт на пару раз, поэтому получилось это. Я попробую поднять `ulimit` но по-моему когда дескрипторов не хватает, то он говорит `too many open files` или что-то такое

Comment: да, но если не ошибаюсь, то и так может, если ему не получилось сделать dns запрос. `мне нужно было быстро накидать скрипт на пару раз,` - вот для этого быстрее было бы ab

Comment: @KoVadim Я не знаю что такое ab, поэтому получилось так, я попробую и отпишу =)

Comment: [ab](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/ab.html) - специализированный инструмент от апача для проверки http серверов. Документации куча, возможностей - тоже

Comment: @KoVadim у меня nginx :D

Comment: @KoVadim у меня сейчас стоит значение 1024, а эта проблема возникает и при 10 потоках (т.е. нет больше 10 запросов одновременно). Неужели в этом может быть проблема?

Comment: это для Вас нет 10 одновременных запросов. А как оно там внутри - это другое дело. Явного закрытия подключения у Вас нет

Comment: @KoVadim я возможно не всё знаю, а как мне закрыть подключение? `client.Do(req)` не делает это сам?

Comment: Да и не может же для 1 http запроса использоваться 100 tcp запросов, это звучит немного странно